# sum the same field twice based on a different field Criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

This is my first question here. I Don't know if the title says it clearly.
I have been stuck on this for the past 5 days. I can't find a solution anywhere in the internet. I'm using Microsoft Access 2013 on Windows 8. I have a very basic knowledge of sql coding.

I have the table below called"CustomerOperationTable"
CustomerName|   OperationDate|  Debit|  Credit|
.--------------------|---------------------|--------|--------|
CustomerA......   | 01/01/2016.....   | 2000 |  0......     |
CustomerA......   | 08/01/2016.....   | 1000 |  0......     |
CustomerA......   | 29/01/2016.....   | 0......    |    2500  |
CustomerA......   | 02/02/2016.....   | 2500 |  0......    |
CustomerA......   | 03/04/2016.....   | 3000 |  0......    |
CustomerA......   | 04/04/2016.....   | 0......    |    4000  |
CustomerB......   | 02/03/2016.....   | 2000 |  0......    |
CustomerB......   | 03/03/2016.....   | 0......    |    4000  |
CustomerB......   | 04/03/2016.....   | 3000 |  0......     |
CustomerB......   | 05/04/2016.....   | 0......    |  1000  |

[The table in a picture made by Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9HQ9.png)

it shows the operations for each customer with its specific date. I'm trying to make a report from a query. Therefore, I need the query to

1. group the table by CustomerName
2. show the sum of Debit and the sum of Credit where the OperationDate is <=31/01/2016 as Debit_OB and Credit_OB
3. show 'again' the sum of Debit and the sum of Credit where the OperationDate is between 01/02/2016 and 01/11/2016

so the result will be like the table below

CustomerName|   Debit_OB|   Credit_OB|  Debit_CB|   Credit_CB|
.---------------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|
CustomerA........   |   3000.......    |    2500.........     | 5500.......    |    4000.........     |
CustomerB........   |   0..............       | 0................        |  5000.......    |    5000.........     |

[The required Query Result made by excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blVUv.png)

I tried a lot of solution I found in the internet but none worked for me.
I would really really appreciate your help.
Happy to provide any information required to accomplished the result.

ps:Please Ignore the extra "....." that were added for formatting purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solutions tend to be troubling, but hey! I got the requested result.
My query was:

```
SELECT YourTable.CustomerName, 
Sum(IIf([OperationDate]<=(#1/31/2016#),[Debit],0)) AS Debit_OB, 
Sum(IIf([OperationDate]<=(#1/31/2016#),[Credit],0)) AS Credit_OB, 
Sum(IIf([OperationDate]>(#1/31/2016#) And [OperationDate]<(#11/1/2016#),[Debit],0)),
Sum(IIf([OperationDate]>(#1/31/2016#) And [OperationDate]<(#11/1/2016#),[Credit],0))
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourTable.CustomerName;
```

AutoMagically works, although performance will be an issue for tens of thousands of records.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very very very much. I really appreciate your help. I have been stuck on this for soooooo long.. Really,Thank you very much for your help,sir ^_^

Comment: @kurrapicazoldik Glad to help. Just mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Your friend, G. Freecs would be happy if you would.
Have a good day.